# WPF App(.NET Core), visual studio isn't allowing me to add a WPF window

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

When I right-click and go to add and select Window(WPF) my options of what I can add to the project doesn't include Window(WPF).
I've seen answers to this problem claim adding '{60dc8134-eba5-43b8-bcc9-bb4bc16c2548};{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}' to the csproj file should resolve it but in my case that didn't help.

Does anyone know what's going on?
[Here its showing the Window(WPF) choice](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HDzkp.png)
[And when I click on it, Window(WPF) isn't there](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zvMmE.png)

Comment: Why would you choose to target net core 3.1 with a new app when there's net 5? <TargetFramework>net5.0-windows</TargetFramework>

Comment: I had this problem for ResourceDictionary in shared projects, the solution was to install **UWP Workload** in Visual Studio Installer

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it! It turns out I didn't have the .NET Desktop Development workload installed. I also had the UWP workload installed.